# How to get array elements' "numeric precision", "numeric scale" and "datetime precision" meta data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, precision, meta, information-schema

For an open source project, I need to get "numeric precision", "numeric scale" and "datetime precision" of arrays in PostgreSQL database.

I'm using [information_schema.columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) and joined it to [information_schema.element_types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-element-types.html) to get info about array elements in columns, but it does not have precision etc.

[element_types page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-element-types.html) states, that (numeric_precision, numeric_scale and datetime_precision) are ***always null, since this information is not applied to array element data types in PostgreSQL***

I thought I misinterpreted this statement, because I can define array columns with numeric precision in tables. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.type_table (
  id SERIAL,
  some_field NUMERIC(4,2) [],
  CONSTRAINT type_table_key PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Also I see some functions `information_schema._pg_datetime_precision()`, `information_schema._pg_numeric_precision()` and `information_schema._pg_numeric_scale()` but could not find them in documentation.

How can I get "numeric precision", "numeric scale" and "datetime precision" of array elements in `columns`, `function arguments` and `domains`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information from [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) and use [`format_type()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get a readable display:

```
select attname, format_type(atttypid, c.atttypmod)
from pg_attribute c
where attrelid = 'public.type_table'::regclass
and attnum > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `format_type` provides precision and scale as a text such as `character varying(20)`, which needs further parsing. If possible, could you please suggest a query for "numeric precision", "numeric scale" and "datetime precision" without parsing?

Comment: @ozm: that information is somehow encoded in `atttypmod` I don't know how to extract that other than using `format_type()`